# MVC++ Static library not generating any exports

Tags: c++, windows, linker, static-linking

**Edit**:

Problem was solved, see below.

I'm trying to generate a static library (not an import library). 
I want to export some C/C++ code into an assembler project. I've done this in the past, but have completely forgotten how to do this, and nothing seems to be working.

For my debug code I use the following C/C++ code (export.cpp):

```
extern "C"
static
int Add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

I compile like this(generates export.obj & export.lib):

```
cl /c /EHsc export.cpp && lib export.obj
```

Dumpbin gives me the following output(dumpbin /EXPORTS export.lib):

```
Dump of file export.lib

File Type: LIBRARY

  Summary

          B0 .debug$S
          2F .drectve
```

I expect the following output (approximation):

```
File Type: LIBRARY

     Exports

       ordinal    name

                  _Add@8
 [snip]
```

**Why is the compiler/linker not exporting my symbols?**

PS.

Other function definitions tried are:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) ...
__declspec(dllexport) int ..
extern "C" int ...
extern int ..
```

I'm almost sure one of these should have worked, but I can't find anyone else who's had this problem (or I just can't google).

The /SYMBOLS flag does show that the function is linked into the object file:

```
008 00000000 SECT3  notype ()    External     | _Add
```

**Edit:**

Problem was solved, I should rely less on what I think I know...

Static libraries are just a bunch of .obj files added together in a single .lib file. My symbol (since it was visible) was available to my assembly project all along.

The problem was that the function definition in my assembly file did not match the symbol name in the .lib file.

Comment: There is no language "C/C++"

Comment: The code, as it currently stands, will compile as either C or C++ code. The language of the code is thus either C/C++.

Comment: That is no valid C code. `extern "C"` is - for obvious reasons - not C.

Comment: Do not edit your question to answer. Instead, post an answer to your question! And: no, "Static libraries are just a bunch of .obj files added together in a single .lib file" is wrong. That is an archive/library (gues that's what the extension stands for). And, yes, that is C++-specific, as C++ uses name mangling.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking something of this nature when creating external functions between C and C++.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern “C” {
#endif

// Function declarations go here, etc.

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

This allows your functions to be 'enabled' by a C linker. Hopefully this is what you were looking for.

Comment: That didn't work, the C symbol was already present in the .lib file. But no symbol was actually exported. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: @user513647 - Have you tried defining the linkage as follows: 
`#ifdef EXPORTING_XYZ_DLL_SYMS
#define XYZ_LINKAGE __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define XYZ_LINKAGE __declspec(dllimport)
#endif`
I found the information here - http://www.lurklurk.org/linkers/linkers.html